# Empty Response - Readability API

Tags: jquery, readability

I was testing Readability API on my localhost with the following jquery code:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url), function( data ){

log(data);

});
```

with the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 10:00:15 GMT
P3P: CP='Legacy Only. Go to https://readability.com/about/terms/ for full terms.'
Server: nginx/1.4.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Cookie
Content-Length: 2601
Connection: keep-alive
```

However, I received empty response. Any idea what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Example url: 

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-25118083&token=1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e

Comment: sorry I was not able to response , still you have same issue ?